# TabBarController only loads a black screen?

Tags: ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

So I am a beginner developer. And simply just want to have a UITabBarController. I started a new View Based app. The followed the steps by Mark, Nutting and LaMarche from iPhone development for Beginners (chapter 7). I have linked the delegate with my tabBar Controller. I have the code in the delegate method:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

This is in didFinishLauchingWithOptions.

I have released the memory. Thats fine.

I have no idea why its just showing a black screen when i run it. It builds perfectly. no warnings or errors.

any help would be greatly appreciated...

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the code - your problem is in your interface builder set up

Comment: I didn't have a window in interface builder. ;)